# How to determine the metaclass of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass

I have a class object, `cls`. I want to know its metaclass. How do I do this?

(If I wanted to know its parent classes, I would do `cls.__mro__`. Is there something like this to get the metaclass?)

Comment: Just `type(cls)`

Comment: @Jim IMO a good answer would explain why the type of a class object is the metaclass it was created with.

Comment: If OP's question is reformatted in a way that actually asks for a *why* and not a *how* then sure @vaultah. As it currently stands I don't personally think it should be re-opened. Feel free to do so if you still believe it's warranted.

Comment: Everything is an object in python. Classes are objects too. Every object has a class associated with it, you can get it by `type(myobject)`. Metaclass is just a class of a class.

Comment: There are specific things to class typing that I don't think are covered in the dup. question, and even if they are, people asking about "finding metaclasses" won't automatically search for "finding an object's type" - the text explaining the two things are the same belongs in an answer to _this_ question. (that is why I asked it to be re-openned)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok - so, a class's metaclass is just its own "type", and can be given by 
`type(cls)` and other means such as  `cls.__class__`.

In Python 3.x there are no further ambiguities - as the syntax for creating a metaclass just passes it as a named parameter on the class declaration statement anyway.

However, the syntax used for creating a metaclass in Python 2.x generates a side-effect that is worth noting.

Upon doing

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
```

The `__metaclass__` attribute is set to that value in the actual class, **even if the actual metaclass is another one**.

Consider:

```
def class_pre_decorator(name, bases, namespace):
     # do something with namespace
     return type(name, bases, namespace)
```

This is a callable that can be used in the metaclass declaration of both Python 2 and 3 - and it is valid. After resolving, the actual metaclass in both cases will simply be  `type`. However, in Python 2.x, `cls.__metaclass__` will point to the callable `class_pre_decorator`, even tough `type(cls)` returns `type`, which is the correct metaclass.(Note that using callables in this way, they will not be used agian when the class is further subclassed)

There is no way in Python 3 to guess the callable actually used  to instantiate a class if it gives no other hint (like setting an attribute on the class) that it was used:

```
# python 2
class A(object):
   __metaclass__ = class_pre_decorator
```

On the console:

```
In [8]: type(A)
Out[8]: type

In [9]: A.__metaclass__
Out[9]: <unbound method A.class_pre_decorator>
```

and

```
# Python 3
class A(metaclass=class_pre_decorator):
    pass
```

And trying to read  `A.__metaclass__` will simply raise an AttributeError.

Comment: I don't think your final example is very clear. Because of the change in syntax for specifying a metaclass between Python 2 and 3, `class_pre_decorator` is **not** the metaclass of `class A(object)`—defining  a class `__metaclass__` attribute like that in Python 3 has no affect on what metaclass gets used (regardless of what kind of value, callable or not, it's given).